# error installing guidedlda on google colab notebook

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I was trying to install guidedlda on google colab notebook but it keeps giving me errors the following code i have used so far.

```
!pip install guidedlda
pip install guidedlda

https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA
cd GuidedLDA
sh build_dist.sh
python setup.py sdist
pip install -e
```

I kept getting the following error. If someone knows how to fix this on google colab please let me know

> Collecting guidedlda   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/ee/6d6e2b3525388399e12a4482554c7529a5fcf5e99c50a60abaa02894b8bf/guidedlda-2.0.0.dev22.tar.gz
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from guidedlda) (1.19.5)
> Building wheels for collected packages: guidedlda   Building wheel for
> guidedlda (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Failed building wheel for
> guidedlda   Running setup.py clean for guidedlda Failed to build
> guidedlda Installing collected packages: guidedlda
> Running setup.py install for guidedlda ... error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys,
> setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1u3r_cht/guidedlda/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1u3r_cht/guidedlda/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record /tmp/pip-record-wpryz4pa/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

You probably saw this, but just in case : https://guidedlda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> If pip install doesn’t work then try the next step.
>
> https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA
>
> ```
> cd GuidedLDA
>
> sh build_dist.sh
>
> python setup.py sdist
>
> pip install -e .
> ```

Comment: yes i did on when i run it gives me syntax error

Comment: please do not format your code snippets as italics (edited).